# Cannot extend HMCExtension class

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I am following the trail [Integration in hmc](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/R5T/Trail+~+Integration+in+the+hMC) to integrate my new extension in hmc. Here while declaring a class CuppytrailHMCExtension I cannot extend HMCExtension class . I am using hybris 5.5.Is HMCExtension class depreciated? What is the alternative to this class? Or there is something need to be done at my end.

Also I cannot import de.hybris.platform.hmc.extension.HMCExtension;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Set dependecies to cuppytrail and hmc (Both in Eclipse and extensioninfo.xml file. Please note, extension name for hmc is hmc)**

Comment: Thanks Benoit. In eclipse I was setting dependencies for cuppytrail instead of cuppytrailhmc. Figured it out and now setted dependencies for cuppytrailhmc to cuppytrail and hmc.